# No more sound devices in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I had everything working well on my Dell Ins 7700 but wanted to change default audio output to HDMI. I installed pulseaudio set default in the app and it worked fine. I then lost audio a few hours later - rebooted and no audio devices at all in the sound control panel. 
I removed and reinstalled pulse audio and the utilities but still no sound devices detected. 
Newer user trying to learn. Please help don't want to have to rebuild my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Found through my own investigation pulseaudio was not running. 
restarted from prompt with pulseaudio --start and devices showed up
then looked in startup applications did not see pulseaudio. I added it back (press the super key- usually the windows key) looked for startup applications and added pulseaudio -- start.
Verified which pulseaudio using termina and the *which pulseaudio* command
Found pulsaudio added it back and rebooted all good now. 
I love learning and fixing it myself